# How to convert JSON payload with reserved keyword as name to record in Ballerina

Tags: type-conversion, ballerina

I'm working on a Ballerina service that receives an event and converts the JSON payload to a record using the `convert` function. The event contains a field with the name `type` which is a reserved keyword in Ballerina. I can't change the payload of the event. Following is a simplified example code that doesn't compile, because of the `string type;` in the `Event` record. Changing `type` to `Type` or `eventType` allows compilation, but the execution throws errors because the field names of the JSON payload don't match the field names of the record.

```java
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/io;

type Event record {
    string id;
    string type;    
    string time;
};

@http:ServiceConfig { basePath: "/" }
service eventservice on new http:Listener(8080) {

    @http:ResourceConfig { methods: ["POST"], path: "/" }
    resource function handleEvent(http:Caller caller, http:Request request) {
        json|error payload = request.getJsonPayload();
        Event|error event = Event.convert(payload);
        io:println(event);
        http:Response response = new;
        _ = caller -> respond(response);
    }
}
```

Here is a `curl` command that sends an example event with a JSON payload and a field with the name `type`.

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080 -H "content-type: application/json" -d "{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"newItem\",\"time\":\"now\"}"
```

I read through Ballerinas [API documentation](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/) and found nothing on this topic.

Coming from the Java world, I would expect something like an annotation on the records field like this:

```
type Event record {
    string id;
    @JsonProperty("type")
    string eventType;    
    string time;
};
```

Has anyone run into this problem and even better found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the Event as follows:

```
type Event record {
    string id;
    string 'type;    
    string time;
};
```

The `'` is used to escape the keyword in Ballerina. 
When accessing it also you can use it as `event.'type`

[Here](https://github.com/riyafa/ballerina-websocket-examples/blob/master/game/game.bal) you can find an example usage.

Comment: Thanks, Riyafa! Did you find this in the documentation?